# Creating graduated symbol classification based on values from multiple columns?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, classification, color-ramp

I have three columns of data, each contains data of a different year

```
Y2015   Y2016  Y2017
131     234    234
442     490    234
1231    543    123
1231    888    111
123     3333   333
```

I would like to apply graduated symbols with the "Quantile" mode to the map, and classify the symbols based on values from all three columns, i.e. but it seems that QGIS only allows me to do it based on one selected column.

I cannot adjust the ranges manually either, since I don't know how to calculate the "Quantiles"in Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A click on the sum symbol next to the column choosing dropdown menu leads you to the expression dialog where you can easily combine all columns in almost any way you like, e.g. sum up all three columns like this:

```
 "Y2015" + "Y2016" + "Y2017"
```

You can type the expression also directly into the column choosing dropdown menu. See also the following screenshot for more information:

[image]

Comment: @iuiu Please, mark the answer by tallistroan as "accepted" if it was useful for you.